# Scaling ImageViews For higher res phones

Tags: android, android-layout, resolution

I have a few ImageViews located near the bottom of my application. When I run in WVGA (Nexus One), everything lines up nicely with the bottom.

When running on another higher res, such as FWVGA, as well as on my Droid 2, there is a space that is left on the bottom of the application.

Is there a way to scale imageviews so that they stretch to fill all the space needed in one or multiple directions?

At the moment I am using an AbsoluteView and my imageview code looks like. I have tried layout_x and layout_y.

```
<ImageView android:layout_height="400px" 
android:id="@+id/widget33" 
android:layout_width="300px" 
android:background="@drawable/picture1" 
android:layout_x="-45dp" 
android:layout_y="216dp">
</ImageView>
```

I have also tried a few other things such as

```
android:baselineAlignBottom
android:padding
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had fixed the `height` and `width` of the imageview.
If you want to set imageview in your whole screen you can use `fill_parent` or `match_parent` if above Android2.2 .

And also I am giving you advice to use relative layout instead of Absolute layout.
In relative layout you can set Views in relative position so that your view will remains same even if the resolution of the device will increase.

And also use unit of length in **`dp`** instead of **`px`** so that your view will remains same in all screen density.

Comment: I don't want it whole screen and I am developing at 2.2, not above it. Thanks for the suggestions I am going to give them a whirl.